# Set hyper-parameters to tune with makeParamSet

Tags: r, random-forest, hyperparameters, mlr

I am running random forest classification in R with `mlr` package. I would like to tune the following hyper-parameters: number of trees, number of variables to consider at each split, terminal node size and tree depth. I am using `makeParamSet` from `mlr` build the set of parameters to be tuned, and here is the code:

```
rf_param <- makeParamSet(
makeIntegerParam("ntree", lower=50, upper =500),  
makeIntegerParam("mtry", lower =floor((ncol(train)-1)/5), upper = ncol(train)),
makeIntegerParam("nodesize", lower =10, upper = 30),
makeIntegerParam("maxnodes", lower =1, upper =100 ))
```

However, in this way each integer from 50 to 500 , in the case of trees, is considered when choosing the optimal trees number. Instead, I would like to evaluate tree numbers by 50 (i.e. 50 100 150 ... 500). Is it possible to do that with `makeParamSet`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `makeDiscreteParam`, like this:

```
makeDiscreteParam("ntree", values = seq(50,500,50))
```

Comment: Great, thanks! And is it possible to use functions in `values= seq()`? Like in the case of  `mtry` parameter, doing something like `makeDiscreteParam("mtry", values =seq((ncol(train))/5),ncol(train),(ncol(train))/5))`? Because it does not seem to work, I'm not sure why..

Comment: yes, it should work, but you have a syntax error in your code there.. If ncol(train)=250, what sequence are you trying to create with that code?

Comment: I would like to evaluate splits with 20% 40% 60% 80% and 100% of variables in my dataset, and I have 106 variables. Obviously I cannot divide the number of variables exactly by 5, maybe there is some way to perform an automatic approximation?

Comment: How about: `makeDiscreteParam("mtry", values = floor(quantile(1:ncol(train), probs = c(.2,.4,.6,.8,1)))`?